# LinkedIn Sales Navigator connection invites limit?

Tags: linkedin, invitation

I'm growing my LinkedIn network for some time already and I send like 100 connection invites through sales now a day. Everything was fine for a few months, but last week or two I sometime encounter a problem - when I'm trying to send invite, I'm every time being asked for user's email in order to proceed. Next day I usually can move on with sending invites as usual.

I could not find any information related to limit of neither invites per day/week/anything, nor pending invites, which I actually remove time to time.

Are there any known rules or limits that I should respect in order to not get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the LinkedIn official link of [Invitation Limitations](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/4800/invitation-limitations?lang=en), which says:

> If you've sent a large number of invitations, your account may be limited from inviting more members. This is generally due to many of your invitations being rejected or ignored by the members you've invited.
>
> If you are unable to send invitations due to this limit, please cancel as many outstanding sent invitations as possible. Once this is complete, you can continue to send invitations to members you know and trust.

Following are the reasons why [Email Address Needed for an Invitation](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/1239/email-address-needed-for-an-invitation?lang=en):

> There are several reasons why you may be asked to enter an email address when you send invitations:
>
> - The recipient's email preferences are set to only receive invitations from members who know their email address.
> - A number of recipients have clicked **I don't know [name]** after getting your invitations.
> - An invitation has already been sent to the member.